# "Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com". Symfony. Swiftmailer

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

- I got exception:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

- Same exception in old project Symfony2.8 and newest Symfony3.
- I can ping `smtp.gmail.com`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Avast Antivirus was guilty.

Answer (score 0):

In Google "Account settings" enable "Access for less secured apps" by setting it to "Allow".

Mailer host is your localhost or 127.0.0.1. It's not smtp.google.com

Comment: Thanks for reply. Same exception with allowed "Access for less secured apps" and mailer_host: 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this configuration for my localhost application

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_user: youremail@gmail.com //replace by your gmail account
    mailer_password: ********** //replace by your gmail password

config.yml:
    swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

your controller code seems to be the same as mine.

As napestershine said in his response do not forget to allow less secure app on your gmail account.