# Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Trying to send email with Swiftmailer, I got this error. I've configured swiftmailer with:

```
transport: smtp
host: smtp.gmail.com
username: example@example.com
password: password
port: 587
encryption: ssl
```

I always get this error message:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

---

I've also tried with:

```
transport: gmail
host: smtp.gmail.com
username: example@example.com
password: password
port: 587
encryption: ssl
```

---

The complete error message is

> [YYYY-mm-dd hh:ii:ss] app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

---

Other questions:

My case is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058392/connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-symfony-swiftma). In my case I've not Avast antivirus.

---

EDIT: changing port to 465, as Alex Howansky suggested, erro changes in

> Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "my email address" using 1 possible authenticators

Comment: Port 587 is not SSL. You probably want port 465. See [here](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-smtp-settings-1170854).

Comment: You might need to toggle the _"Use Less Secure Apps"_ setting as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098781/script-sending-mails-with-gmail-failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server).

Comment: Already done. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Is your username a gmail account, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

1: Either you must allow less secure apps or use app password by enabling 2 step verification on your gmail acc.
2: Disable any antivirus on your machine(this is something no one will tell u but is necessary in many cases).
3: Don't forget to clear your cache (sometimes it don't take updated content from .env file)
4: You don't need to change anything in Mailer inside config directory(not recommended), you should use env variables

Answer (score -1):

it's looking for the server smtp.gmail.com but isn't able to resolve it. use this domain smtp.gmail.com and port 25 or 465.

Comment: who is looking for "mail.website.com"?

Comment: so, ... you are suggesting to change smtp.gmail.com:465 to smtp.gmail.com:465. Interesting.

Comment: i guess u are using port 587  which u have shown on your question

Comment: Yes, but I've update the question as Alex suggested. Error is changed.

Comment: Yes, again, as Alex suggested.